# How jQuery $ is initialized? How it is used globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

You know that when we `<script>` include `jquery.js` in our page, we can then use it like this:

```
$.ajax();
```

My question is that, is jQuery already initialized in jquery.js? Because we are not going to use `new` operator. Can anyone tell me how the initialization happens? Since we immediately have an instance of jQuery ready.

Comment: `$` is just a variable name like any other.  In the jquery script a variable named `$` is created.

Comment: Funamentially, this happens: `var $ = function() {}; $.ajax = ...;`.

Comment: Well I know it is a variable, but I expect it to be like this: $ = new jQuery();

Comment: Specifically:  `window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery`  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js

Comment: under the hood, it creates a new instance of the `jQuery` object, which is a wrapper for the internal API.

Comment: Thanks much, I was seeking to know if there happens an initialization.

Comment: // Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery; ....is defined as a global object inside of the jquery script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the jquery javascript file you will see in the very bottom of the file something like

```
var
    // Map over jQuery in case of overwrite
    _jQuery = window.jQuery,

    // Map over the $ in case of overwrite
    _$ = window.$;

jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
    if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
        window.$ = _$;
    }

    if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
};

// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

**You can see right there at the very bottom of the text the jQuery library sets the window.$ variable = jQuery itself and that is why your page knows what $ is :)**

You should be able to find this text at the very bottom of the jquery-{version}.js file

Answer (score 5):

A function is just an object, and a dollarsign is just a variable

```
function $(something, more) {
    return new $.fn.init(arguments);
}

$.fn = $.prototype;

$.fn.init = function() {
     // get elements and stuff
}

$.ajax = function(params) {
    // send ajax
}
```

which means you can create a function with the name `$`, and add properties to it that are also functions in themselves, and jQuery does create a `new` instance for you internally when calling the `$()` function directly, but `$.ajax` is a different function that is just added as a property to `$`

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery script creates a global variable `$`.

In Javascript, you can do without using the `new` operator, unlike Java. It only depends on the people building the API for the objects you want to use.

Example:

```
// Creating an Object with new
var obj = new Object();

// Same without new
var obj2 = {};
```

When building a library:

```
// `new` will be needed (or you could change the scope of 'this')
var fooFactory = function() {
  this.getColor = function() { return 'blue'};
}
var obj = new fooFactory();
obj.getColor(); // -> 'blue'

// no 'new' needed
window.bar = {
    getColor: function() { return 'blue' }
}
var obj2 = bar; // no 'new' here
obj.getColor(); // -> 'blue'
```

Comment: I read once that `new` was added to please Sun when Mozilla, who had created Livescript, wanted to rename it as Javascript because Java was fancy at the time and that would make it more popular. (Of course, the issue is that people still get confused thinking Javascript and Java are the same thing or very similar)

Answer (score 1):

To be perfectly clear, after loading jQuery, `$` is a function in global scope. You can use a different symbol for it by calling `jQuery.noConflict`, but whatever.

In Javascript, you can append properties to functions just like any other object. This allows behavior similar to `static` members of classes in Java/C#/C++/etc. Probably the most important static member of any function is its `prototype`, as that allows you to add functions and properties to all variables constructed by that function using the `new` operator. However, there's nothing preventing you from adding functions directly to the original function.

```
var __ = function(s) {
    this.string = s;
};

__.bacon = function() {
    return "delicious!";
};

var el = document.getElementById("bacon");
el.innerHTML = __.bacon();
```